# Inner join in mysql error

Tags: php, mysql

I have two tables `tbl_expense` and `tbl_miscellaneous_category`. In `tbl_expense` i have some fields. mainly `id` and `category`.In  `tbl_miscellaneous_category id and name`. the name is nothing but `category` in `tbl_expense table`. I need o/p like this: id name

```
SELECT te.id,te.category  
FROM tbl_expense te 
         inner join tbl_miscellaneous_category  tmc 
                on te.category=tmc.id 
WHERE te.id= '1'
```

Comment: SELECT 
    te.id, tmc.name 
FROM 
    tbl_expense te inner join tbl_miscellaneous_category tmc 
        on te.category=tmc.id WHERE te.id= '1'

Comment: You only SELECT te.id, te.category, which are both ID's. Just add the category name to the SELECT.

Comment: since you are joing the table and you want the name of the categfory, use `tmc.name` instead of `te.category`

Answer (score 0):

Its not too clear what you're looking for but I believe the following would work:

```
SELECT 
    te.id, tmc.name 
FROM 
    tbl_expense te inner join tbl_miscellaneous_category tmc 
        on te.category=tmc.id WHERE te.id= '1'
```

This solution will provide the category name as provided by the `name` column in `tbl_miscellaneous_category`.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of `te`, use `tmc` which contains name of the `category`

```
SELECT   te.id, 
         tmc.name 
FROM     tbl_expense te 
              INNER JOIN tbl_miscellaneous_category tmc 
                 ON te.category = tmc.id 
WHERE    te.id = '1'
```